# PHP Show Trailing Zero on Non-Decimals

Tags: php, mysql

I have a number stored in MySQL:

5430

PHP only displays:

543

How can I retain the last zero? Some numbers do not contain zeros.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, they're two different numbers. If this were the case, there'd be nothing distinguishing `543` from `5430000`, etc. You should have 5430 in PHP too.

Comment: What data type is it being stored as in the database? Can you show a snippet?

Comment: The structure is int(4) unsigned zerofill

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$number = str_pad($number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);`

This will turn `1` into `1000` or `123` into `1230`. If you wanted `0001` or `0123`, you can use `STR_PAD_LEFT` instead.

Here's the docs for `str_pad()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 0):

try number_format()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php